# Is the span of all invertible functions equal to the span of all functions?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, nonlinear-system

In Koopman analysis, [any non-linear dynamical system can be exactly represented as an infinte dimensional linear operator acting on a Hilbert space of all functions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1076052/). I am looking to prove that the same property holds (or doesn't hold) when you look at only invertible functions.

I think this comes down to the question of showing equality between the span of invertible functions and the span of all functions - but I am not really familiar with how to do this, or if this is even a well posed question as I have presented it

Comment: I don't know anything about Koopman theory, but: 1) by "Hilbert space if all functions", you mean "Hilbert space of all square-integrable functions"?  2) By "invertible", you mean "vanishing nowhere"? 3) The "space" of invertible  functions is not a vector space.

Comment: 1) I don't think I mean just square-integrable functions although I think this set of functions does span the same space. 2) By invertible I mean that there exists a $g$ such that if $f(x) = y$, $g(y) = x$ which probably means vanishing nowhere and that $f$ is bijective. 3) I don't think this is a problem since I am not trying to span the space of invertible functions. The goal is to span the (infinite dimensional) space of all functions using an (infinite dimensional) basis set of invertible functions.